# How does the spell "Find Steed" work with Aura of Vitality?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, animal-companions

Could my steed also heal other people such as myself and others in my party? I am finding it hard to find anything in RAW that explains if my Find Steed can use this spell as its own spell.

Comment: Better yet, if you're Oath of the Crown (or multiclassing) you can do the same thing with Spirit Guardians. Now that is deadly.

Answer (score 11):

You can, when casting it, have *Aura of Vitality* affect both you and your steed OR you alone, it cannot just affect your steed (PHB p.240):

> While mounted on your steed, you can make any spell you cast that targets only you also target your steed.

You must be mounted when you cast the *Aura of Vitality* but its effects persist if you dismount.

*Aura of Vitality* says (PHB p.216):

> You can use a bonus action to
>   cause one creature in the aura (including you) to regain
>   2d6 hit points.

Since this is affecting both you and your steed you can each do this on your respective turns. Even though a controlled mount is limited to only the Dash, Disengage or Dodge *actions* it can use any *bonus actions* it qualifies for. Of course, *Find Steed* describes the mount as "unusually intelligent" so you probably have the option of allowing it to act independently.

Comment: With Find Steed (and Find Greater Steed) you should probably leave the mount uncontrolled anyway. Since it's loyal, intelligent, and telepathically linked to you, the only downside to letting it act independently is the rare case where you're far apart in the initiative order and that limits your options.

Comment: Aura of vitality doesn't target only you, it also has an AoE. See @ruse's answer for correct ruling

Answer (score 4):

## *Aura of vitality* does not work with *find steed*.

> While mounted on your steed, you can make any spell you cast **that targets only you** also target your steed.

*Aura of vitality* targets you, an area of effect, and every creature that you heal with a bonus action. As such it does not work with *find steed*.

Moreover, [this Sage Advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/05/22/find-steed-spells-that-target-only-you/) confirms that spells that target self with a parenthetical area of effect don't work with *find steed*.

Comment: Another related Sage Advice about Find Steed and the smite spells: https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/08/03/blinding-smite-and-find-steed-does-the-spell-qualify-for-find-steeds-spell-effect-duplication/

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, *aura of vitality* can be cast on your steed

Per the *find steed* spell (PH240),

> While mounted on your steed, you can make any spell you cast that targets only you also target your steed.

PH202 defines what "targets only you" means:

> Other spells, such as the *shield* spell, affect only you. These spells have a range of self.

Lastly, PH216 lists *aura of vitality* as having a range of self.

As long as you're mounted on your steed, you can target it instead of you with any aura spell.

### Caveats

- As mentioned in the *find steed* spell description, you must be mounted on your steed to target it with a spell. Meaning you can't be fighting on foot and cast *aura of vitality* on your steed back over by the wizard
- It's a concentration spell, so you can't have more than one aura going

Comment: I guess I may of worded it wrong but, I was meaning more as, does my steed also have the Aura of Vitality? So in others words I guess, can he have the spell and use it because I casted it on myself?

Comment: You cast the spell, and it either targets you *or* your steed, not both. It's still *your* spell, so you need to use your bonus action to heal.

Comment: Okay, so I don't mean me. It is my spell but as it is worded the Steed also gets it, so does it own concentration not come into account ?

Comment: *You* cast the spell, not the steed. Therefore, it is *your* spell and *you* must concentrate on it. Just like if a wizard were to cast *haste* or *fly* on another character, the wizard is the one who cast the spell and must be the one to concentrate on it.

Comment: @Christopher It targets both you and your steed. That's what "also" means.

Comment: I don't believe the querent is *necessarily* asking whether Aura of Vitality can also target the steed. Given the line *"Could my steed also heal other people"* it appears they're asking whether the steed can (use a bonus action to) heal a creature within the spell's radius.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey if that is the actual question, then I need to do a complete rewrite of my reply. rubenZ, is that what you're asking?