# Does a Paladin's steed (Find Steed) need to concentrate while sharing Aura of Vitalty?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, paladin, concentration

This question assumes that the steed is acting independently.

Is the Steed responsible for maintaining the concentration requirements for a shared Aura of Vitality spell?

Comment: The concentration part of the question is new, I suppose. Also, it's not "Twinned spell", technically. That terminology strongly evokes Sorcerer Metamagic, and is thus inappropriate here.

Comment: Since the question in the title is already asked and answered elsewhere, and since we have a one question per post policy, I've edited this to be about the second question and removed the first (duplicate) question.

Answer (score 4):

As asked and answered in [How does the spell "Find Steed" work with Aura of Vitality?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88970/how-does-the-spell-find-steed-work-with-aura-of-vitality), the steed can use its bonus action irrespective of if it is acting independently or not. A controlled steed has its *actions* limited, its *bonus actions* are unaffected.

As for concentration, it's the *paladin's* spell so only the paladin's concentration matters.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think the answer stands as the OP stipulates an independent steed